# ¿Por qué se me hace negativo el número en mi calculadora una vez le doy la operación resta?

Tags: javascript

Código html:

```js
var cifra="";
    var acumulado=0;
    var suma=false;
    var resta=false;
    function display_numeros(numero){   
     document.getElementById("display").value=cifra+numero;
        cifra=document.getElementById("display").value;
    }
    
    
    function sumar()
    {
        acumulado=acumulado+parseInt(cifra);
        document.getElementById("display").value=acumulado;
        cifra="";
        suma=true;
    }
    
    function reset(){
        cifra=0;
        document.getElementById("display").value=cifra;
        acumulado=0;
    }
    
    function restar()
    {
      acumulado=acumulado-parseInt(cifra);
      document.getElementById("display").value=acumulado;
      cifra="";
      resta=true;
        
    }
    
    function resultado()
    {
        if(suma){
          
            document.getElementById("display").value=acumulado+parseInt(cifra);
        }    
    }
```

```css
    
            .reset{
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
            }
        .numero{
         width:60px;
         height:60px;
         
         
        }
        
        .igual{
         width:160px;
         height:60px;
         
        }
        
        table{
         margin:auto;
            width: 20%;
        }
        
        .color_display{
         height:30px;
         background-color:#000;
         border:medium #FFF;
         font: "Space Age";
         color:#0F0;
         font-size:18px;
         text-align:right;
         padding:5px;
        }
        
            .C{
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>

        

    </head>
    
    <body>
    <table  border="1">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
        <input name="display" type="text" class="color_display" id="display" style="width:96%" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="26%"><input name="button" type="button" class="numero" id="button" value="+" onclick="sumar()"></td>
        <td width="21%"><input name="button2" type="button" class="numero" id="button2" value="-" onclick="restar()"></td>
        <td width="21%"><input style="width:100%"name="button3" type="button" class="numero" id="button3" value="*" ></td>
        <td width="32%"><input style="width: 100%" name="button4" type="button" class="numero" id="button4" value="/" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="num7" type="button" class="numero" id="num7" value="7" onclick="display_numeros(7)"></td>
        <td><input name="num8" type="button" class="numero" id="num8" value="8" onclick="display_numeros(8)"></td>
        <td><input style="width: 100%"name="num9" type="button" class="numero" id="num9" value="9" onclick="display_numeros(9)"></td>
        <td><input class="reset" type="button" value="C" style="width: 100%" onclick="reset()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="num4" type="button" class="numero" id="num4" value="4" onclick="display_numeros(4)"></td>
        <td><input name="num5" type="button" class="numero" id="num5" value="5" 
        onclick="display_numeros(5)"></td>
        <td><input name="num6" type="button" class="numero" id="num6" value="6" style="width: 100%" onclick="display_numeros(6)"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="num1" type="button" class="numero" id="num1" value="1" onclick="display_numeros(1)"></td>
        <td><input name="num2" type="button" class="numero" id="num2" value="2" onclick="display_numeros(2)"></td>
        <td><input name="num3" type="button" class="numero" id="num3" value="3" style="width:100% "onclick="display_numeros(3)"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="num0" type="button" class="numero" id="num0" value="0"onclick="display_numeros(0)"></td>
        <td><input name="button17" type="button" class="numero" id="button17" value=","></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="button12" type="button" class="igual" id="button12" value="=" onclick="resultado()"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
       // document.getElementById("display").value=0;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Mi problema es el siguiente: cuando voy a restar por ejemplo presiono el 9 y en la pantalla me sale el 9. pero una vez le presiono el signo negativo este no se me queda esperando el otro número sino que el 9 lo hace negativo. Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hace falta mucho código javascript, y sobre todo el html y los eventos de cada botón para poder buscar el error, con esto que pones no dice nada

Comment: Lixus ahi esta el codigo html

Comment: Osea que en lugar de pasar `9` a `9-`lo cambia a `-9`?

Comment: Si inviertes esta linea   **acumulado=acumulado-parseInt(cifra);** por **acumulado = parseInt(cifra) - acumulado;**

Comment: @jasilva si eso mismo

Comment: Tu función `restar()` no tiene forma de saber si es el primer número que se ingresa en la calculadora ni tampoco forma de esperar a que se de click en el botón `=`, por lo que al terminar la función setea tu input igual a esto `acumulado = acumulado - parseInt(cifra)` -> `0 = 0 - 9 -> -9` que es el resultado incorrecto que te está regresando.

Comment: @Lixus es que efectivamente no lo he terminado ni aun quiero que con el boton = me de el resultado. En realidad lo estoy haciendo de a poco. lo que quiero primero es que a medida que yo vaya presionando - me vaya restando. Lo de ejecutarlo con el igual lo haré despues.

Answer (score 0):

se te hace negativo por que por definicion los numeros son tanto positivos como negativos , si deseas que no sea asi, debes validar si es menor a cero y usar la funcion javascript "abs" para saber quitar el resultado negativo o preguntar si es un numero negativo

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp